# How to keep function argument format?

Tags: functions

```
function! test(address, ...)
   echom a:address
   return
```

If run `:call test(0x000)`, I'll get 0.
How to keep `a:address = 0x000`? Because I want to populate address width from the input address argument. For example, 0x000 means address width is 3.

Comment: Maybe string? `let a = 0x000 echo a` also displays 0. Or you can add another argument to indicate the format.

Comment: Fundamentally 0 = 0x000. If you want to output in a different format, that's one thing, but if you just need (say) bit manipulations, they don't depend on being able to see the difference. (See `:help printf()` for outputting.)